# Optaplanner, How to make the lecture start time to be chosen within time window according to the constraints in DRL and not an input specific time?

Tags: optaplanner

In the curriculum course example, I want the lecture to start within a time window and according to its duration the constraints between two consecutive lectures are set. Defining the constraints in the DRL file is not the problem, I've already tried it with a fixed lecture start time but I want to make the lectures start time to be chosen from a period (time window) and satisfying the constraints.
I want to make the inputs earliestStartTime and latestStartTime as inputs and the used start time for each lecture to be chosen between these two boundaries.

i.e Lecture Time x belongs to [earliestStartTime, latestStartTime], and x should be chosen by the program within this range and ofcourse satisfying the defined constraints.
what I have successed in is that I made x to be the input and I obtained the output as a schedule determining the order of the lectures according to the defined constraints. Now I want to make x as a variable determined by the program and the inputs will be the earliestStartTime and the latestStartTime.

Comment: [This blog post on time scheduling patterns might be usefull](http://www.optaplanner.org/blog/2015/12/01/TimeSchedulingDesignPatterns.html)

Comment: thanks for your answer, I'm using version 6.2.0 can I adapt my work to use what you explained or I must use version 6.4.0?

Comment: The info of that post will work with 6.2 too. But there's no reason not to upgrade to the latest Final version.

Comment: I'm afraid that upgrading may causes some problems with my project, and I have a dead line to finish. So I prefer to stick with the version I begin with in order not to be late.

Comment: [Read the upgrade recipe](http://www.optaplanner.org/download/upgradeRecipe/) to avoid upgrading problems.